# Does a finite Vector space imply a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is:

Consider a finite vector space V over a field F where |V| > 1. Is F always finite?

My proof: Suppose for a contradiction that F was infinite. Since V is closed under scalar multiplication any element from our field, say c, multiplied by 1 will give us back c, which is in V. Since F has infinitely many elements this implies V will also have infinitely many elements. This is a contradiction since V is finite. Hence F must also be finite.

Is this proof sound?

Comment: $c$ is in the field?  Then why is $1$ necessarily in $V$?  Note that $1$ is not an element of, for instance, $\Bbb R^2$.  Since $1$ is not necessarily in $V$, how can we word it to not make mention of the "element $1$"?

Comment: Sorry I was being lazy, by 1 I meant the multiplicative identity, 1v = v for all v ∈ V.

Comment: And yes, c is any scalar from the field

Comment: Then c times 1 is a scalar times a scalar, is not in V but rather it's in F

Comment: "For closure under multiplication, we demand that if u ∈ V, a ∈ F, then aF∈ V". My understanding is that any vector multiplied by a scalar must be in the set. Since the multiplicative identity is in V, every scalar must also be in V. Is this incorrect reasoning?

Comment: "*since the multiplicative identity is in $V$*"  No.  $F$ will have a multiplicative identity.  There only needs to be scalar multiplication defined where one of the multiplicands is a scalar and the other is a vector.  Multiplication of two vectors does not need to be defined.  There does not need to be a vector who acts as a multiplicative identity.  The only "$1$" that makes sense to talk about here would be the multiplicative identity of the field.

Comment: I again refer you to the example of $\Bbb R^4$ or similar.  A scalar would be something like $0$ or $1$ or $\pi$ or $-\frac{3}{2}$ or similar.  A vector would be something like $[1,0,1,-2]$ or $[\pi, -\pi, 8,0.7]$ or similar.  We have multiplication here of a scalar with a scalar as usually defined, such as $2\cdot 7  = 14$.  We have multiplication of a scalar with a vector such as $3\cdot [1,2,0.5,0] = [3,6,1.5,0]$.  The "element $1$", the multiplicative identity, is a scalar here... *not a vector!*  There is no "multiplicative identity vector" and no scalar here is also a vector.

Comment: $\Bbb R^4\cap \Bbb R = \emptyset$, in this example no scalar is a vector and no vector is a scalar.  Every product between a scalar and a vector results in a vector, and in this example never the other way around, so no, it is impossible to take a scalar $c$ and multiply it by some vector $\vec{v}$ such that $c\vec{v}=c$.  In this running example of $\Bbb R^4$ here on the right, $c$ is just a solitary number.  Meanwhile $c\vec{v}$ is a quadruple, a totally different type of object.

Comment: I see now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $F$ is not finite. Let $v\neq 0, v\in V$, consider the map $f:F\rightarrow V$ defined by $f(x)=xv$, there exists $x,y$ not zero, $x\neq y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ this implies that $(x-y)v=0$, by multiplying by the inverse of $(x-y)$ we deduce that $v=0$ contradiction.